# Getting error as no such directory or file in Artifact Version in shell script file

Tags: shell

cannot access '/opt/tca/dcae-analytics-cdap-tca*.jar': No such file or directory

```
  CDAP_HOST='localhost'
  CDAP_PORT='11015'
  TCA_NAMESPACE='cdap_tca_hi_lo'
  TCA_APPNAME='dcae-tca'

  TCA_ARTIFACT='dcae-analytics-cdap-tca'
  TCA_FILE_PATH='/opt/tca'
  TCA_JAR="$(ls -1r ${TCA_FILE_PATH}/${TCA_ARTIFACT}*.jar | head -1)"
  TCA_ARTIFACT_VERSION=$(echo "$TCA_JAR" |rev |cut -f 2-4 -d '.' |rev)
  TCA_APP_CONF="${TCA_FILE_PATH}/tca_app_config.json"
  TCA_CONF="${TCA_FILE_PATH}/tca_config.json"
  TCA_PREF="${TCA_FILE_PATH}/tca_app_preferences.json"
  TCA_CONF_TEMP='/tmp/tca_config.json'
  TCA_APP_CONF_TEMP='/tmp/tca_app_config.json'
  TCA_PREF_TEMP='/tmp/tca_preferences.json'
```

Comment: What do `ls /opt/tca/.` and `ls /opt/tca/dcae-analytics-cdap-tca*.jar` show?

Comment: i didn't get u r point @jhnc

Comment: Perhaps the error message is exactly what it says. Do the directory and any files exst?

Comment: yes that is the error@jhnc

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `jar` file doesn't exist when executing the statement:

```
ls -1r ${TCA_FILE_PATH}/${TCA_ARTIFACT}*.jar
```

Check existence of the files at the `${TCA_FILE_PATH}` before listing down.